# printing the duplicates characters in a line with same characters

Tags: java

I am trying one problem that is : 
*Print the duplicate values line by line from an array i.e each line having same character*

Example :

```
char[] arr1={a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,e,e,g,f,h};
```

output should be like :

```
aaaa 
bbbb
cccc  
ee 
g 
f 
h
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Please, don't post question without trying anything, see [ask]

Comment: What language is that?? It doesn't appear to be Java or JavaScript...

Comment: Please post the code as well what you tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure input is sorted first, i.e. with Arrays.sort(). Once it is you can loop over the input and print each character. Whenever the next character is different print a new line.

Another alternative would be to create some kind of storage of counts of each character, e.g. LinkedHashMap(), but that would be over engineering IMO.

```
char[] arr1 = { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'f', 'h' };

Arrays.sort(arr1);
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    char each = arr1[i];
    System.out.print(each);
    if (i + 1 < arr1.length && arr1[i + 1] != each) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
ee
f
g
h
```

Comment: thank you very much both ways are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may Help you... Executed

```
class Arr12 
       {
           public static void main(String[] args) 
{ char[] arr1=new char[]  {'a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','e','e','g','f','h'}; 

    String text = String.copyValueOf(arr1);//Converting Char[] to String


    String[] strArr= text.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");//This is Regular Expression
 for (int i=0;i<strArr.length ;i++ )//Printing
        {
            System.out.println(strArr[i]);
        }
}
  }
```

Comment: If u understood above solution please Accept it @madan